# Replacing Kitchen Sanitary T

Tags: plumbing

[image]

A Question and a recommendation are requested here. I have to replace my kitchen sanitation T. The old sink had Dual Sink Drains (one on a garbage disposal). The original installation has a "loop" in the drain system with what I presume, was a "clean out" on the other side of the loop.

- Just wondering, why would it have been installed this way (what purpose does the loop serve)?
- Second question, is the original sanitation T appears to be a 2x2x2 sanitation T, with maybe a "threaded" female end to the sink drain line. It also appears a Male Threaded 2x1.5" reducer was placed on the horizontal portion of the sanitation T. The remaining sink drain lines appear to be 1.5" lines. I looked all over and could not find a 2x2x2(female threaded) Sanitation T that would then be reduced to 1.5". Why couldn't a 2x2x1.5 sanitation T be used to complete the horizontal drain line from the Sink?

The new sink will only have one drain with the garbage disposal.

[image: Sanitary T Loop]

Comment: Is the sink in an "island" in the kitchen? The loop looks like a half-right, half-wrong attempt at Island venting.

Comment: No, it's not in an island.

Comment: That loop is totally bizarre.  The two vertical pipes are just connected at the top?

Comment: You need a proper vent here.

Comment: Yes, the two vertical pipes are connected at the top as shown in the pic.  It really is a "loop".  The wall that this is in, is a "pass through" (it's open just above it), that goes into another room.  I suspect that the "Vent" is below the floor (no access to verify).  Found a pic online with a very similar configuration when i Googled "island sink venting".    Still looking for feedback on my second question.

Comment: ...but that's only "like" an island sink vent. It's not a properly implemented island-type sink vent, when the two pipes each join the drain, separately, not join each other like this.